# How do I save console output in Xcode to a file?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I wish to save the console output in Xcode to a file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, but you can use [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) which is a logging framework that can output to both the XCode console and to plain text files (and Apple System Logger, for that matters)

Comment: You can use os_log https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/oslog-unified-logging/#setting-up-oslog